# Wine running apps stops download when downloading big files

Tags: installation, .net-framework, wine

If I am trying to install the .Net framework in Wine. It has to download data around 200-300 MB.
It starts well. But after downloading 10-20 MB the download stops. Installation is still running, even the download speed going up and down as usual. But the download percentage will not be moving.

I am sure its not the issue with the .Net installer. Some other software also gave the same issue.

Comment: who ever -1ed the question please put a comment. I still believe its a bug with wine. have you ever tried downloading a big game in origin... it will start well but wont finish ..

Answer (score 0):

For best results use the [winetricks](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks) script to install .NET as detailed [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&ild=2586):

```
winetricks dotnet30
winetricks dotnet35
```

Comment: I used that also. 
Finally I have to use a standalone installation of .net framework..

Comment: Which version of .NET was it? Regarding your comment above, you do realise Wine is nowhere close to perfect, right? It's reverse engineering and trying to reimplement proprietary closed-source software/APIs, so don't expect it to perform miracles. If something works, just be thankful, and if it doesn't use Windows in a VM instead.

Comment: I know wine is not a perfect option. But it is a very basic requirement.have you ever tried downloading a big game in origin... it will start well but wont finish .same thing here also. it might be some kind of memory leak. And the wonderful part is wine helped me to run a BIG 6GB game(fifa 13) without much issues.